# Obtaining attribute data at given GPS coordinates?

Tags: qgis, gps, coordinates, attribute-joins, qgis-3

I have a csv file containing information at given lat and lon GPS coordinates, as well as a shapefile containing, among other things, annual average daily traffic (AADT) values along stretches of road in NYC (TDV_Shapefile_AADT_2015.zip from https://www.dot.ny.gov/tdv).

What I'd like to do is create a bridge to map each GPS coordinate in my csv file to the closest AADT value in my shapefile.

Is this possible in QGIS3?

I'm a total GIS beginner.

What I've been able to do so far is upload a sample of my data as a layer onto my shapefile. What I need to do now is obtain match each point with the closest AADT value.

NYDOT has an online tool [here](https://gis3.dot.ny.gov/html5viewer/?viewer=tdv) using the data from the shapefile I'm using. If you zoom in, especially in NYC, you can see most streets have a color and a value. What I want is to get that value for each point in my csv.

Comment: The NNJoin plugin will join features from the input layer with their nearest neighbors in the join layer. http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/NNJoin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NNJoin plugin will join features from the input layer with their nearest neighbors in the join layer. [See full plugin description here.](http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/NNJoin)

**1. Go to the plugin menu > manage and install plugins. Find and install the NNJoin plugin.**
 [image]
 **2. Both shapefiles should be in the same *projected* coordinate reference system.** If not, convert one or both of them. Right click on the layer name in the layers panel, choose save as... and select a projected coordinate system.
[image]
 **3. Use the NNJoin plugin.** 
[image]

Use the points layer as input, and road layer as join.

[image]

The tool will create a new layer. The new layer is a copy of the input layer, with the attributes copied from the nearest features of the join layer.

[image]

**4. Save the new layer as a csv. Don't forget this step!**

Comment: Click the green check mark next to this answer to accept it as correct. This way other users will know that this solution is useful.